# How to wait until specific text is on screen before proceeding with script?

Tags: applescript

Im a relative newcomer to applescript and so any help at all would be much appreciated!

I am trying to get my script to only run when specific text presents itself on a webpage. I have been trying to search for help for my query and so far have come up dry.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AppleScripts cannot monitor events unless the target application provides specific event handlers in its AppleScript dictionary.

A workaround is using a repeat loop to monitor periodically the state of the requested event but this is quite expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the idle handler in a stay-open applescript application. The idle handler lets the code run at specified interval in seconds.
You can start with this code. Save as an application, and check for it to "Stay open after run".

```
property browserName : "Safari"
property searchString : "google"
property theDelay : 60  -- delay time in seconds

on run
    -- do any setup here
end run

on idle
    -- do your stuff here
    tell application "System Events" to set appRunning to ((name of processes) contains browserName)
    if appRunning then
        tell application "Safari" to set t to the text of document 1
    end if
    if t contains searchString then
        -- do stuff
        beep

    end if
    return theDelay
end idle

on quit
    -- do any cleanup necessary upon quit
    continue quit
end quit
```

Another approach is to use the launchd utility in OS X to run a script at a specified time or interval. Here's a good tutorial for it: http://nathangrigg.net/2012/07/schedule-jobs-using-launchd/